# Windows 10 Freeze on Logo at startup, safe mode and usb installation without loading circle

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, freeze, uefi

today my new PC arrived and, as lucky as I am, I got some problems.

First things first, the hardware:

- Gainward RTX 3060 Ti
- 16 GB Ballistix RAM 2666 MHz
- AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
- MSI A520M-A Pro
- A Crucial SSD with 480 GB

I started by trying to install windows with an USB stick, but when he tried to start the setup, he froze on the blue windows 10 logo. There wasnt even the loading circle. When I pressed the power button, it shut down immediately. Doesnt he normally need some seconds to turn off?

So I switched the UEFI to CSM, but still got the same issue. I've then installed a ISO with Rufus on the same USB stick, hoping this will work, but it didnt. So I plugged the SSD out and drove to my mother. On her computer I plugged my ssd in and installed windows using the same USB stick. There it worked just fine. On my pc it didnt work with UEFI and CSM mode. So I installed windows there and the ssd worked fine.

When I was back home I plugged the ssd back into my new computer and, again as lucky as I am, it didnt work. He opened the bios. From there I saw that my ssd is shown up in the bios, but in the boot menu there wasnt any hard drive. When I switched to CSM again I was able to boot from the ssd in the boot menu, but then I got the same issue again. So when I want to install windows with an USB stick, it freezes at the blue windows logo (without the loading circle). Same with booting from the ssd where I've installed windows on.

I already tried to get into safe mode, but also there he stucks at the logo. The only difference is, that on the safe mode he showns me the text on the bottom. But thats the only difference, everything still the same. I've also tried to swap the RAM sticks, but that also didnt make a difference. When booting the pc the motherboard blinks at the gpu and cpu led and then the boot led. But the dram led doesnt. Is there anything wrong with the ram maybe?

Does anyone know whats happening there? Im grateful for every answer! Thanks for reading :)

// Edit: I've tried Media Creation Tool before using Rufus

// Edit 2: Installed Ubuntu on my USB stick and it's booting properly. I can use it without problems (I've clicked on "try ubuntu" instead of installing it)

// **SOLUTION:** I updated my bios to a newer version (thought I had the newest one, then I saw the xxx.100 in my bios and xxx.130 on MSI website), after that I installed Linux (Ubuntu) on my ssd and after that I was able to boot from the ssd (there was no partition) and now I plugged my USB stick back in with windows 10 on and now it's working just fine and I'm installing it right now. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It is new. Did you contact the Seller for support?  I would do this first as the machine should come with warranty.

Comment: Who is "he" in this story?  Sounds like a problem with your Rufus settings.  You should be using the Media Creation Tool.  It's less prone to user error.  **You should absolutely NOT enable CSM.** You should keep UEFi mode enabled.  Instead of submitting a comment you should [edit] your question

Comment: Edited my question, I've first did it with the media creation tool, but that didnt work so I was on google and found something with rufus. "He" is the pc

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into your question. Stack Exchange doesn't work that way. You are quite welcome to add your own answer & mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your BIOS version and update to the latest version if it is not up to date.

Please note the manufacturer's notes for bios updates before you flash the update!

Then try the Windows Installation again.

Friendly greetings

Sorry for any mistakes. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to add a comment, but not enough rep.

As Tekkie_boy answered, update BIOS (if you bought a built one, it may not be the root cause but it's entirely possible, as ZEN 3 need newer BIOS to work properly).

It could be a bad usb stick. But as you tested in another PC, we may skip this.

Bad windows installation can be caused by Bad RAM or some weird conditions. If XMP is enabled, disable it and try to install Windows again.

Disable CSM,leave it UEFI. Also, make sure SATA is working as AHCI.

Wish you success.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** I updated my bios to a newer version (thought I had the newest one, then I saw the xxx.100 in my bios and xxx.130 on MSI website), after that I installed Linux (Ubuntu) on my ssd and after that I was able to boot from the ssd (there was no partition) and now I plugged my USB stick back in with windows 10 on and now it's working just fine and I'm installing it right now. Thanks for the answers!